# Kernel + Cokernel

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to find a good website explaining how to find the cokernel and kernel of a matrix. Would somebody please direct me to one or explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cokernel and kernel of a matrix are actually the cokernel and kernel of the linear map from $\mathbf R^n$ to $\mathbf R^m$ associated with the matrix, if the matrix has size $m\times n$.

The *kernel* is then the set of vectors in $\mathbf R^n$ that map to $0$.

The *image*  is the  set of vectors in $\mathbf R^m$ that are images of the vectors in $\mathbf R^n$.

The  *cokernel* supposes you know what is a quotient space. It is made up of the vectors of $\mathbf R^m/\operatorname{Im} A$, i.e. the cosets of vectors in $\mathbf R^m$ modulo vectors of $\operatorname{Im} A$

Similarly, there exist a *coimage* of the linear map/matrix, which is the quotient  $\mathbf R^n/\ker A$. We have a canonical decomposition of the linear map :
\begin{matrix}\mathbf R^n\!&\mkern-20mu\xrightarrow{\quad f\quad}&\mathbf R^m\\
p\downarrow&&\uparrow i \\[-1ex]
\mathbf R^n/\ker A&\xrightarrow[\sim]{\quad \overline f\quad}&\operatorname{Im} A
\end{matrix}
where $p$ is the canonical surjection, $i$ is the canonical injection and $\overline f$ is an isomorphism of the coimage onto the image of $f$.

Comment: That's incorrect. The _cokernel_ is the quotient of the **codomain** $R^m$ by the image of $A$. See also [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra) for example.

Comment: @ShlomiA: You're right. I don't even remember why I messed up with cokernel and coimage. Thanks for pointing it! I've fixed and completed the answer.